# How to use tabs as carousel?

Tags: angularjs

I wouldn't like to use a third parties libraries to have carousel on a site. Md-tabs have very similar features, even with swipe gesture and I thought, setting time interval between tabs could be possible. It should work like [this](http://blog.revolunet.com/angular-carousel/).

**The Goal**

Make next active tab after a time interval and circle it around infinitely.

Comment: What have you tried to implement so far? What has been the challenge in your implementation. Do you have a codepen or plunkr of the code you are having issues with.

Comment: I have only theory. No idea how to start.

Answer (score 1):

Although I don't really have much information on what you are trying to accomplish or what challenges you have met, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33741115/create-a-carousel-of-divs-with-tables-in-it-and-previous-and-next-divs-partially/33742518#33742518) covers some controller based functionality for a carousel.